# Apache NiFi Distributed Performance

Tags: apache-nifi, flowfile

I have a file which is approximately 40GB in size, my nifi cluster runs on one node, and takes around 60 minutes to decompress. If I have this Processor over 2 or 3 nodes does the processor distribute its work for the decompress time to go down to 30, 25 minutes? Thanks in advance

Comment: does anybody know of such tech ? decompress single file using muliple compute node ?

Answer (score 2):

If the file is a single compressed collection of data, you won't be able to distribute this across multiple nodes because the decompression can't occur in parallel. If this is a file which contains multiple independently-compressed pieces of data that are simply concatenated together, then yes, you could split the data into its component pieces and distribute them to multiple nodes to be decompressed in parallel.